# how do I make entire menu item clickable instead of only text in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I want to make entire menu item area clickable instead of only text. I had refered net and tried a lot but nothing gave me solution.

This is my CSS class for menu item:

```
    .temp {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        text-align:center;
        font-size:15px;
    }
```

I had included this css class as follows:

```
     <asp:Menu ID="Navigation" runat="server">
       <StaticMenuItemStyle  Height="30px" CssClass="temp" />
       <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="White" />
       <DynamicMenuItemStyle BackColor="#0080c0" CssClass="temp"   />
       <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="temp" width="132" BackColor="#99CCFF" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css as below

```
<asp:Menu ID="Navigation" runat="server" CssClass="menu">


.Menu
{  
   width:100%; 
}

.Menu ul li
{

    width:100%;
}
```

This link may also help you http://forums.asp.net/post/2192957.aspx 
Similar question on SO

1. [How can I make asp.net menu of 100% width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168528/how-can-i-make-asp-net-menu-of-100-width)
2. [ASP Menu width not setting to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368872/asp-menu-width-not-setting-to-100)
3. [How to style ASP:Menu with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214202/how-to-style-aspmenu-with-css)

Comment: all these links I had already seen and tried but these are not working